# Python glob module is not working with multi selection?

Tags: python, linux, glob

In linux, my folder looks like that:

```
src
├── app
│   ├── app.component.css
│   ├── app.component.html
│   ├── app.component.spec.ts
│   ├── app.component.ts
│   ├── app.module.ts
│   ├── app-routing.module.ts
│   ├── components
│   │   ├── catalog-main
│   │   │   ├── catalog-main.component.css
│   │   │   ├── catalog-main.component.html
│   │   │   ├── catalog-main.component.spec.ts
│   │   │   └── catalog-main.component.ts
│   │   ├── catalog-sidebar
│   │   │   ├── catalog-sidebar.component.css
│   │   │   ├── catalog-sidebar.component.html
│   │   │   ├── catalog-sidebar.component.spec.ts
│   │   │   └── catalog-sidebar.component.ts
│   │   └── top-bar
│   │       ├── top-bar.component.css
│   │       ├── top-bar.component_handy.css
│   │       ├── top-bar.component_handy.html
│   │       ├── top-bar.component.html
│   │       ├── top-bar.component.spec.ts
│   │       └── top-bar.component.ts
│   ├── icons-provider.module.ts
│   ├── pages
│   │   ├── login
│   │   │   ├── login.component.css
│   │   │   ├── login.component.html
│   │   │   ├── login.component.spec.ts
│   │   │   ├── login.component.ts
│   │   │   ├── login.module.ts
│   │   │   └── login-routing.module.ts
│   │   ├── monitor
│   │   │   ├── monitor.component.css
│   │   │   ├── monitor.component.html
│   │   │   ├── monitor.component.spec.ts
│   │   │   ├── monitor.component.ts
│   │   │   ├── monitor.module.ts
│   │   │   └── monitor-routing.module.ts
│   │   ├── monitor2
│   │   │   └── monitor2.module.ts
│   │   └── welcome
│   │       ├── welcome.component.css
│   │       ├── welcome.component.html
│   │       ├── welcome.component.ts
│   │       ├── welcome.module.ts
│   │       └── welcome-routing.module.ts
│   ├── reducers
│   │   └── index.ts
│   └── store
│       ├── catalog.actions.ts
│       ├── catalog.reducer.ts
│       └── userinfo.ts
├── assets
├── environments
│   ├── environment.prod.ts
│   └── environment.ts
├── favicon.ico
├── index.html
├── main.ts
├── polyfills.ts
├── styles.css
├── test.ts
└── theme.less
```

I use this command output 29 files:`ll src/**/*.ts | wc -l`
I use this command output 32 files:`ll src/{**,}/*.ts | wc -l`, new files are src/main.ts, src/test.ts, src/polyfills.ts, they are direct in src folder

But in python3,
I use `glob.glob("src/**/*.ts")` output all 32 files,
I use `glob.glob("src/{**,}/*.ts")` output all 0 files

So, which is standard glob syntax?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> which is standard glob syntax?

Because you tagged `linux` I assume you use `bash`. Bash has *nostandard* (ie. it's not in posix) extension not related to globbing [brace expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Brace-Expansion.html).

The:

```
ll src/{**,}/*.ts | wc -l
```

is first expanded to:

```
ll src/**/*.ts src/*.ts | wc -l
```

by bash when doing brace expansion. Then *next* happens globbing expansion. Python does not do any shell expansions when parsing glob arguments, so python searches for files/directories named `{` and ending with `,` and `}` taken literally as characters - as it finds none, the count is 0.

So you are not comparing globbing, you are comparing globbing with shell expansion with only globbing. You can compare your commands with bash with brace expansions disabled `set +B` or use another shell without brace expansions, like busyboxs.

Answer (score 0):

Neither. The [man page for the POSIX function glob(3)](https://linux.die.net/man/3/glob) allows neither syntax.

** is an extension, invented and first popularised by zsh. Bash and some others copied it and generally did something slightly incompatible. Bash and Python both copied it, but chose slightly different behaviour when interacting with other globbing syntax.

This makes sense: After all, while glob(3) is a POSIX function, precisely specified and to be implemented exactly as specified, zsh is merely a role model, from one one can deviate at will. And one has to deviate, because [zsh has a *lot* of globbing extensions](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Filename-Generation).